# Upload Facebook profile picture using FBSDKProfileExpressionKit - swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fbsdk

I am using FBSDKProfileExpressionKit.framework.

I am trying to upload photo error is occurred.

> invalid image cannot upload try again.

In ViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uplodeImage.image!, 0)
        FBSDKProfileExpressionSharer.uploadProfilePicture(from: data! as Data, metadata: nil)
        FBSDKProfileExpressionSharer.wasLaunchedFromFacebook()
        print("set")
    }
```

In AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    FBSDKProfileExpressionURLHandler.parseIncomingURL(url)
    return true
   }
```

**My question :-**

can i upload profile picture to facebook?

Comment: you cannot upload profile picture on the Facebook here is the link - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/

Comment: availble. Link - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/profile-expression-kit/ios#uploading

Comment: @SagarBhut are there any pods for this SDK?

Comment: yes abou given link provide full detail

Answer (score 1):

You can't upload profile picture with Graph-Api.

You can upload profile picture with [FBSDKProfileExpressionKit](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/profile-expression-kit/ios)

You must have latest Facebook App and also check the image Size and Dimension

You can upload photo and video as follow

```
[FBSDKProfileExpressionSharer uploadProfilePictureFromData:videoData metadata:nil];

[FBSDKProfileExpressionSharer uploadProfilePictureFromUIImage:uiimage metadata:nil];
```

More info :- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/profile-expression-kit

Comment: is there any pods for this SDK?

Comment: there is a FBSDK check here  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/profile-expression-kit

Comment: @VaibhavJhaveri No pod available in cocoa pod and also there is a no documentation about pods